# IntelliJ IDEA bundled Gradle Extension plugin won't start

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I can't get the IntelliJ IDEA bundled Gradle Extension plugin to start.

In the list with plugins I get the following message:
[image: Gradle Extension with error]
If I click proposed the link the message disappears but nothing really happens.
[image: Gradle Extension without error]
When I restart IDEA the error reappears.

The only useful thing I can detect in the log are these 2 lines:

```
2021-05-21 13:16:25,332 [  15802]   INFO -   #com.intellij.AbstractBundle - Cannot load resource bundle from *.properties file, falling back to slow class loading: messages.GradleExtBundle 
2021-05-21 13:16:25,333 [  15803]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find plugin org.jetbrains.idea.gradle.ext resource-bundle: messages.GradleExtBundle
```

I rebooted my system, I uninstalled & re-installed IDEA, nothing seems to work.

What Else can I try?

The log: `tail -f ~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/log/idea.log`

```
2021-05-21 13:16:14,622 [   5092]   INFO - penapi.wm.impl.GlobalMenuLinux - can't start main loop via JavaFX (will run it manually): com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl 
2021-05-21 13:16:15,741 [   6211]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Indexes to be rebuilt after corruption:FilenameIndex(v = 3),FrameworkDetectionIndex(v = 65536),TodoIndex(v = 4107),IdIndex(v = 4113),filetypes(v = 3),Stubs(v = 46),Trigram.Index(v = 4099),fileIncludes(v = 6),DomFileIndex(v = 0),RelaxSymbolIndex(v = 0),XmlTagNames(v = 1),XmlNamespaces(v = 8),html5.custom.attributes.index(v = 1),SchemaTypeInheritance(v = 2),json.file.root.values(v = 5),HashFragmentIndex(v = 19115599),HtmlTagIdIndex(v = 3),XsltSymbolIndex(v = 0),CssIndex(v = 34),css.template.selectors(v = 30),CompassFunctionsIndex(v = 33),xmlProperties(v = 2),editorconfig.index.name(v = 5),yaml.keys.name(v = 1),bytecodeAnalysis(v = 4107),java.auto.module.name(v = 5),java.source.module.name(v = 3),java.null.method.argument(v = 4097),java.fun.expression(v = 4102),java.binary.plus.expression(v = 4100),docker.compose.services(v = 1),LombokConfigIndex(v = 11),groovy.trait.fields(v = 5),groovy.trait.methods(v = 32),java.cucumber.java8.step(v = 4097),js.test.names(v = 22),js.package.index(v = 12),js.custom.single.entry.index(v = 291),js.implicit.elements.index(v = 985),js.string.literal.words.index(v = 3),TypeScriptExternalPathCandidates(v = 0),angularjs.template.cache(v = 65),angularjs.ui.router.views.index(v = 65),angularjs.app.index(v = 65),sql.types.count.index(v = 0),sql.routine.index(v = 1),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJvmMetadataVersionIndex(v = 5),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJsMetadataVersionIndex(v = 3),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinClassFileIndex(v = 3),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJavaScriptMetaFileIndex(v = 4),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFileIndex(v = 1),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFilePackageIndex(v = 1),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinModuleMappingIndex(v = 5),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinPackageSourcesMemberNamesIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJvmModuleAnnotationsIndex(v = 1),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KlibMetaFileIndex(v = 4),taglibUris(v = 7),SpringXmlBeansIndex(v = 608),spring.spiFileIndex(v = 3),FileBasedWSIndex(v = 6),FtlFileIndex(v = 5),spring.autoConfigureMetadataIndex(v = 2),http.request.execution.environment(v = 3),http.request.completion.host(v = 5),http.request.headers.values.index(v = 4),OpenapiSpecificationContentIndexer(v = 8) 
2021-05-21 13:16:15,756 [   6226]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Index data initialization done: 2235 ms. Initialized indexes: [FilenameIndex, filetypes, IdIndex, TodoIndex, Trigram.Index, DomFileIndex, RelaxSymbolIndex, fileIncludes, XmlTagNames, XmlNamespaces, html5.custom.attributes.index, SchemaTypeInheritance, json.file.root.values, HtmlTagIdIndex, HashFragmentIndex, XsltSymbolIndex, FrameworkDetectionIndex, CompassFunctionsIndex, xmlProperties, css.template.selectors, CssIndex, editorconfig.index.name, java.auto.module.name, bytecodeAnalysis, yaml.keys.name, java.source.module.name, java.fun.expression, java.null.method.argument, java.binary.plus.expression, groovy.trait.fields, docker.compose.services, LombokConfigIndex, groovy.trait.methods, java.cucumber.java8.step, js.package.index, js.test.names, js.string.literal.words.index, TypeScriptExternalPathCandidates, angularjs.template.cache, angularjs.ui.router.views.index, js.custom.single.entry.index, angularjs.app.index, js.implicit.elements.index, sql.types.count.index, sql.routine.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJvmMetadataVersionIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinJsMetadataVersionIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinClassFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJavaScriptMetaFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFilePackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinMetadataFileIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinModuleMappingIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinPackageSourcesMemberNamesIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KotlinJvmModuleAnnotationsIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.vfilefinder.KlibMetaFileIndex, taglibUris, spring.spiFileIndex, FileBasedWSIndex, spring.autoConfigureMetadataIndex, FtlFileIndex, SpringXmlBeansIndex, http.request.execution.environment, http.request.completion.host, http.request.headers.values.index, OpenapiSpecificationContentIndexer, Stubs]. 
2021-05-21 13:16:15,838 [   6308]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - Following stub indices will be built:dom.namespaceKey(v = 1),dom.elementClass(v = 0),Css.ampersand.selector(v = 2),Css.class(v = 2),Css.id(v = 2),Css.attr(v = 2),Css.custom.property(v = 2),Css.custom.mixin(v = 2),Less.mixins(v = 2),Less.variables(v = 2),Scss.variable(v = 2),Scss.placeholder.selector(v = 2),Scss.function(v = 2),Scss.mixin(v = 2),properties.index(v = 2),gr.class.fqn(v = 1),gr.script.fqn(v = 2),gr.field.name(v = 2),gr.method.name(v = 2),gr.annot.method.name(v = 2),gr.annot.members(v = 2),gr.script.class(v = 2),gr.class.super(v = 2),gr.anonymous.class(v = 3),markdown.header(v = 2),js.qualified.shortName(v = 4),js.element.qualifiedName(v = 3),JS.global.qualified.elements(v = 3),ts.external.module.index(v = 3),JS.class.super(v = 5),JS.class.implements(v = 3),JS.custom.stub.index(v = 2),js.symbol.index2(v = 6),js.typedef.index2(v = 2),js.generics.index(v = 2),JS.base.types.index(v = 3),js.class.index2(v = 3),js.namespace.index(v = 2),js.local.namespace.members.index(v = 2),JS.subclass.stub.index(v = 2),js.symbol.qualified.names.index(v = 1),amd.baseUrl.index(v = 2),amd.requirePaths.index(v = 2),js.global.symbol.index(v = 2),js.exported.index(v = 2),es6.exported.index(v = 2),js.imported.bindings.index(v = 2),es6.assignment.index(v = 2),ts.local.classes(v = 2),ts.embedded.content.index(v = 2),js.nonglobal.symbol.index(v = 2),js.lazy.packages(v = 3),js.gcl.modules(v = 2),js.doc.modules(v = 2),js.amd.modules(v = 2),angularjs.directives.index(v = 65),angularjs.directives.doc.index(v = 65),angularjs.controller.index(v = 65),angularjs.module.index(v = 65),angularjs.filter.index(v = 65),angularjs.symbol.index(v = 65),angularjs.ui.router.states.index(v = 65),angularjs.ui.router.generic.states.index(v = 65),angularjs.templateUrl.index(v = 65),angularjs.generic.modules.index(v = 65),angularjs.delimiter.index(v = 65),angular2.templateUrl.index(v = 9),angular2.source.pipe.index(v = 9),angular2.source.directive.index(v = 9),angular2.source.module.index(v = 9),angular2.ivy.pipe.index(v = 9),angular2.ivy.directive.index(v = 9),angular2.ivy.module.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.pipe.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.className.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.directive.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.node.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.function.index(v = 9),angular2.metadata.module.index(v = 9),sql.table.shortName(v = 3),sql.column.name(v = 3),sql.names(v = 21),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExactPackagesIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelClassByPackageIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionByPackageIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyByPackageIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasByPackageIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinClassShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFullClassNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinPropertyShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFunctionShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinSuperClassIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionFqnNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyFqnNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasFqNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelExtensionsByReceiverTypeIndex(v = 3),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExtensionsInObjectsByReceiverTypeIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinAnnotationsIndex(v = 3),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingFunctionShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingPropertyShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyContractedFunctionShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeFqNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFilePartClassIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeClassByPackageIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinMultifileClassPartIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinScriptFqnIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasByExpansionShortNameIndex(v = 2),org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinOverridableInternalMembersShortNameIndex(v = 2),java.annotations(v = 2),java.class.extlist(v = 3),java.field.name(v = 2),java.method.name(v = 2),jvm.static.member.name(v = 2),jvm.static.member.type(v = 2),java.anonymous.baseref(v = 2),java.method.parameter.types(v = 3),java.class.shortname(v = 4),java.class.fqn(v = 1),java.module.name(v = 4) 
2021-05-21 13:16:15,839 [   6309]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Index data initialization done: 82 ms. Initialized stub indexes: {Css.ampersand.selector, angular2.source.directive.index, JS.base.types.index, java.method.parameter.types, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionByPackageIndex, js.gcl.modules, js.lazy.packages, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeFqNameIndex, angular2.source.pipe.index, gr.annot.members, gr.method.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyContractedFunctionShortNameIndex, gr.annot.method.name, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingFunctionShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinProbablyNothingPropertyShortNameIndex, gr.field.name, Css.id, angular2.ivy.pipe.index, angular2.templateUrl.index, dom.namespaceKey, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinClassShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasByPackageIndex, Css.class, angular2.source.module.index, angular2.ivy.directive.index, Css.attr, dom.elementClass, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelClassByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExactPackagesIndex, sql.names, JS.subclass.stub.index, JS.custom.stub.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFullClassNameIndex, gr.anonymous.class, jvm.static.member.name, es6.assignment.index, Css.custom.mixin, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeClassByPackageIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinAnnotationsIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelExtensionsByReceiverTypeIndex, Scss.mixin, angularjs.templateUrl.index, angularjs.delimiter.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinMultifileClassPartIndex, gr.script.class, angularjs.directives.index, angularjs.controller.index, gr.class.fqn, js.namespace.index, amd.baseUrl.index, es6.exported.index, js.typedef.index2, js.doc.modules, js.qualified.shortName, JS.class.super, java.field.name, ts.embedded.content.index, java.anonymous.baseref, java.module.name, java.class.shortname, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinOverridableInternalMembersShortNameIndex, angular2.metadata.node.index, Scss.variable, js.global.symbol.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinSuperClassIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelFunctionFqnNameIndex, js.element.qualifiedName, java.annotations, JS.global.qualified.elements, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasByExpansionShortNameIndex, Less.variables, Scss.placeholder.selector, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelPropertyFqnNameIndex, angularjs.ui.router.states.index, angularjs.module.index, angularjs.symbol.index, angularjs.filter.index, Less.mixins, Scss.function, angularjs.ui.router.generic.states.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTopLevelTypeAliasFqNameIndex, angular2.metadata.className.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinTypeAliasShortNameIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFunctionShortNameIndex, angular2.metadata.pipe.index, angular2.metadata.function.index, angular2.metadata.directive.index, sql.table.shortName, sql.column.name, angular2.metadata.module.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFileFacadeShortNameIndex, angular2.ivy.module.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinExtensionsInObjectsByReceiverTypeIndex, angularjs.generic.modules.index, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinPropertyShortNameIndex, java.method.name, Css.custom.property, ts.local.classes, gr.class.super, js.amd.modules, properties.index, angularjs.directives.doc.index, gr.script.fqn, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinScriptFqnIndex, org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.stubindex.KotlinFilePartClassIndex, jvm.static.member.type, markdown.header, js.nonglobal.symbol.index, ts.external.module.index, js.imported.bindings.index, JS.class.implements, java.class.extlist, js.local.namespace.members.index, js.class.index2, js.generics.index, js.symbol.qualified.names.index, js.symbol.index2, js.exported.index, amd.requirePaths.index, java.class.fqn}. 
2021-05-21 13:16:17,089 [   7559]   INFO - erver.followMe.FollowMeManager - Register new user 0:'nxd' with ClientId=ClientId(value=Host) 
2021-05-21 13:16:25,332 [  15802]   INFO -   #com.intellij.AbstractBundle - Cannot load resource bundle from *.properties file, falling back to slow class loading: messages.GradleExtBundle 
2021-05-21 13:16:25,333 [  15803]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find plugin org.jetbrains.idea.gradle.ext resource-bundle: messages.GradleExtBundle 
2021-05-21 13:16:56,434 [  46904]   INFO - ication.options.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {MAVEN_REPOSITORY=/home/nxd/.m2/repository, KOTLIN_BUNDLED=/home/nxd/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/211.7142.45/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: opened `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/disabled_plugins.txt` and removed any Gradle related line there.

Solution provided by JetBrains support staff: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3314884